# Applying timed functions recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner

I am relatively new to JavaScript/jQuery, and cobbled together a script. Essentially, the script sets individual timers on specific DOM elements, and then recursively applies timed functions to them. The functions actually apply a "flip" effect to a div, showing a front and back, and then do different things on each side. The references to "Vague" are from Vague.js, and external library I didn't write that provides a blur effect to elements. The script works, but writing working code and writing good code are two separate things.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.flipper').each(function(e) {
        var flipper = new myFlipper($(this));
    })
});

var myFlipper = function (flipper) {
    //console.log(flipper);
    this.flipper = flipper;
    this.image = flipper.find('img');
    this.blurStatus = true;
    this.flipStatus = true;
    this.Vague = this.image.Vague ({
        intensity: 8,
        forceSVGUrl: false
    });
    this.blurContext = $.proxy(this.myBlur, this);
    this.flipContext = $.proxy(this.myFlip, this);
    // $(this.image).on("click", this.blurContext);
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var timer = randomNumber * 1000;
    setTimeout(this.blurContext, timer);
}

myFlipper.prototype.myBlur = function(e) {
    console.log(this.flipContext);
    if(this.blurStatus) {
        this.Vague.blur();
        this.blurStatus = false;
        this.flipper.find('.caption').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000);
        setTimeout(this.flipContext,5000);
    } else {
        this.Vague.unblur();
        this.blurStatus = true;
    }
}

myFlipper.prototype.myFlip = function(e) {
    console.log(this.flipper.attr("class"));
    console.log(this.flipStatus);
    if (this.flipStatus) {
        this.flipper.addClass('hover');
        this.flipper.find('.caption').animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000);
        this.blurContext();
        this.flipStatus = false;
        setTimeout(this.flipContext, 20000);
    } else {
        this.flipper.removeClass('hover');
        this.flipStatus = true;
        setTimeout(this.blurContext,5000);
    }
}
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K33t6/1/) of the whole thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might not be an improvement per se, but you can change this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.flipper').each(function(e) {
        var flipper = new myFlipper($(this));
    })
});
```

To this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.flipper').each(function(e) {
        var flipper = new myFlipper($(this));
    });
});
```

The reason this works is `$()` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready()`.

With JavaScript, it is usually recommended that you keep from cluttering the global namespace. You currently have everything contained in `var myFlipper`, which is good. But since you're using jQuery, you might as well use a [jQuery plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), which would allow you to do something like this:

```
$.fn.myFlipper = function () {
    //...
};

$(function() {
    $('.flipper').myFlipper();
});
```

This way, you aren't introducing another variable into the global namespace. Plus, the jQuery plugin architecture affords you some additional benefits, like syntax, etc.

Comment: On the second example:with `$('.flipper').myFlipper();`, I would NOT need to pass $(this) like I do to my current function because it's passing it to the function automatically, correct? Would I even need the 'each' function at that point, or would the plugin interact on each .flipper element as separately?

Comment: Additionally, using the plugin route, are my prototype calls still valid? Do I need to address myFlipper in the $.fn namespace when I refer to it, like: `$.fn.myFlipper.prototype...` or would the current syntax still be valid?

Comment: To your first question: correct, you would not need to pass `$(this)` to the jQuery plugin. The `each` function would be in the plugin code. To your second question: I would assume you can use `prototype` inside a jQuery plugin, but I've never tried it. Read [this](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), post your revisions, and we can critique some more.

Answer (score 2):

From a once over,

- You are not doing anything with `flipper` in `var flipper = new myFlipper($(this));` you might as well just `new myFlipper($(this));`
- Of course, that  shows that `myFlipper` is not the best of names, perhaps simply `Flip`?
- If you are not going to use `e`, then you do not need to declare it as a variable
- As @DavidKennedy mentioned, you can simply use

  ```
  $(function() {
      $('.flipper').each(function() {
          new myFlipper($(this)); //Or startFlipping( $(this) );
      });
  });
  ```
- Please indent inside your functions for readability
- Production code does not use `console.log`
- Production code does not have commented out code
- You can show the flipping of the boolean blurStatus better like this:

  ```
  if(this.blurStatus) {
    this.Vague.blur();
    this.flipper.find('.caption').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000);
    setTimeout(this.flipContext,5000);
  } else {
    this.Vague.unblur();
  }
  this.blurStatus = !this.blurStatus; //<- Flipping happens here
  ```
- The following code seems too long to me:

  ```
  var randomNumber = ;
  var timer = ;
  setTimeout(this.blurContext, timer);
  ```

  I would write it likes this, you should find a middle ground.

  ```
  setTimeout(this.blurContext, Math.floor(Math.random()*10000 );
  ```

  Since there is not much difference between say 8 seconds or 8.345 seconds, I just used `Math.random()*10000`
- Consider using `$.toggleClass('hover')` instead of setting or removing it each time in `if` blocks.
- You should use for strings either all single or all double quotes, the preference du jour is single quotes
- You have some constants like `5000` that you repeat, consider using named constants instead

Comment: Thanks for this, too. I'm going to work on incorporating these changes and repost my new code. As for the indentation, I think it's an artifact from pasting code here. It's indented in Sublime Text, but not when I paste it. I don't know how to add 4 spaces to every line I paste except manually, so I just indent the flush lines. until the snippet all lists as code.